# OpenGL two pass shader effect with FBO render to texture gives noise in result on Windows only

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, textures, fbo

What is the correct way of doing the following:

1. Render a scene into a texture using a FBO (fbo-a)
2. Then apply an effect using the texture (tex-a) and render this into another texture (tex-b) using the same fbo (fbo-a)
3. Then render this second texture, with the applied effect (tex-b) as a full screen quad.

My approach is this, but this gives me a texture filled with "noise" on window + the applied effect (all pixels are randomly colored red, green, blue  white, black).

- I'm using one FBO, with two textures set to GL_COLOR_ATTACHENT0 (tex-a) and GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 (tex-b)
- I bind my fbo, make sure it's rendered into the tex-a using glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)
- Then I apply the effect in a shader with tex-a bound and set as 'sampler2D'. Using texture unit 1, and switch to the second color attachment (glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1)). and render a full screen quad. Everything is now rendered into tex-b
- Then I switch back to the default FBO (0) and use tex-b with a full screen quad to render the result.

*Example of the result when applying my shader*
[image: enter noise]

This is the shader I'm using. I'm not aware this could be what is causing this, but maybe the noise is caused by a overflow?

**Vertex shader**

```
attribute vec4 a_pos; 
attribute vec2 a_tex; 
varying vec2 v_tex; 

void main() { 
    mat4 ident = mat4(1.0); 
    v_tex = a_tex; 
    gl_Position = ident * a_pos; 
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
uniform int u_mode; 
uniform sampler2D u_texture; 
uniform float u_exposure; 
uniform float u_decay; 
uniform float u_density; 
uniform float u_weight; 
uniform float u_light_x; 
uniform float u_light_y; 
const int NUM_SAMPLES = 100; 
varying vec2 v_tex; 
void main() { 
    if (u_mode == 0) { 
        vec2 pos_on_screen = vec2(u_light_x, u_light_y); 
        vec2 delta_texc = vec2(v_tex.st - pos_on_screen.xy); 
        vec2 texc = v_tex; 
        delta_texc *= 1.0 / float(NUM_SAMPLES) * u_density; 
        float illum_decay = 1.0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++) { 
            texc -= delta_texc; 
            vec4 sample = texture2D(u_texture, texc); 
            sample *= illum_decay * u_weight; 
            gl_FragColor += sample; 
            illum_decay *= u_decay; 
        } 
        gl_FragColor *= u_exposure; 
    } 
    else if(u_mode == 1) { 
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_tex); 
        gl_FragColor.a = 1.0; 
    } 

}
```

I've read this [FBO article](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) on opengl.org, where they describe a feedback loop at the bottom of the article. The description is not completely clear to me and I'm wondering if I'm exactly doing what they describe there.

**Update 1:**

[Link to source code](https://gist.github.com/11d7b8ee5db1283dc2a8#comments)

**Update 2:**

When I first set `gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);` before I start the sampling loop (with NUM_SAMPLES), it works find. No idea why though.

Comment: This looks like it could be an incorrectly bound texture, could you post your FBO/texture setup code?

Comment: StuGrey, I added the link at the bottom of the post.

Comment: StuGrey, also added a fix... though no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not initializing `gl_FragColor`, and you're modifying it with the lines

```
gl_FragColor += sample;
```

and

```
gl_FragColor *= u_exposure;
```

both of which depend on the previous value of gl_FragColor.  So you're getting some random junk (whatever happened to be in the register that the shader compiler decided to use for the gl_FragColor computation) added in.  This has a strong possibility of working fine on some driver/hardware combinations (because the compiler decided to use a register that was always 0 for some reason) and not on others.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I fixed it indeed by setting gl_FragColor.